# Nuget Package Manager Console equivalent for Manage checkbox

Tags: powershell, versioning, nuget

When clicking "Managing Nuget Packages for Solution", the Nuget Package Manager UI allows to Manage an installed package. Checking a checkbox next to a project installs the same version of that already installed package in the project.

Is there a Package Manager Console command equivalent to this?

The Install-Package command always looks for the latest version unless you use the -Version parameter. But I usually don't know by heart which version I already have installed. So how do I say in the console: Just install the latest version already installed in one of the projects of this solution?

Is this possible?

Comment: There is no way to do this from VS without enabling package restore, which will munge your solution. However, we are actually creating a Visual Studio extension that will, in additional to all the NuGet extension functionality, allow you to sync packages with whatever's in packages.config (and of course, much more). We're getting close to the beta phase if you're interested in it.

Comment: Sounds interesting indeed. I'm not quite sure what influence enabling package restore has on this matter. And I have no problem with package restore "munging" my solution as long as I keep attentive to the package versions I'm installing...

Answer (score 1):

There's not a direct command to do so, but you can achieve it indirectly by using the -Source parameter. Try this:

```
Update-Package <id> -Source <path to the packages folder under solution root>
```

Comment: You probably meant Install-Package... Thanks for the -Source parameter tip, I didn't know you could specify a packages folder as source. +1